# Remapping <C-a> in Vim causes jumping

Tags: vim

Long ago I remapped tmux' `C-b` to `C-a`, to save my left index finger from becoming grotesquely elongated.

Now I find I need to remap vim's `C-a` to something else as a result. I'm trying to remap it to `C-i`, with:

```
nnoremap <C-i> <C-a>
```

Which works, but when I press C-i on a number, the cursor jumps down a line after incrementing said number.

How is one supposed to remap a key properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, you should

```
nn <C-i> <C-a>
```

which make `ctrl-i` behave like `ctrl-a`.

As to recover the default behavior of `ctrl-a`, use

```
nn <C-a> <C-a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! *edited answer to reverse C-a & C-i, as I mean to map C-a functionality to C-i*.

Comment: Please could you give me a link to where `nn` is documented?

Comment: @MichaelRobinson please use `:help :nn` for the manual you need. Actually, it's the alias of `:nnoremap`

Comment: Thanks @AdeYU and @FDinoff, new to Vim and keep forgetting about the excellent `:help` command.

Comment: hi I have the same issue where `<C-a>` is a keybinding for `tmux`. I tried remapping in `init.vim` file `nn <C-i> <C-a>` but it doesn't increment (but `<C-x>` decrements fine). I have nvim 4.4. Any ideas?